# IHasXmlNode .net core 1.x

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

Trying to port following lines of code created with `.NET Framework 4.0` to `.NET Core 1.1`.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode node = ((IHasXmlNode)doc.CreateNavigator()).GetNode();
```

error

> The type or namespace name 'IHasXmlNode' could not be found

`IHasXmlNode` [seems to be available](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Xml.IHasXmlNode) since `.NET Core 2`

Can i retrieve current node *(`GetNode()`)* from `XPathNavigator` on `.NET Core 1.1` ?

Comment: If that's the *actual* code, it looks like an overly complicated way to write `doc.DocumentElement`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's just a simplified version of code around the problem.

Comment: The details matter, because there's almost always more than one way to skin a cat when it comes to XML navigation. (I was wrong: the line *as written* simply returns the original `XmlDocument`, so you see why asking for details is not pointless. If you can simplify the whole expression out of existence it's easy to get it working...)

Comment: Good news (sort of): you can stop worrying about extracting the node from the `XPathNavigator`, because [`XmlDocument.CreateNavigator` doesn't exist in .NET Core 1.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.createnavigator?view=netcore-1.1). `XmlDocument` doesn't implement `IXPathNavigatable` in .NET Core 1.1 (hence, there's no need for the `IHasXmlNode` interface, no type implements it). Depending on what your code is doing, you could work with an `XPathDocument` instead, but this can get iffy if the code also has to modify the XML document.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for you research. Not sure why ms docs states that `CreateNavigator` is not supported in `.NET Core 1.1`, but it does exists in `system.xml.xpath.xmldocument` Nuget package for .net 1.1

Comment: Well, it's an extension method, so maybe the automated docs generator got tripped up. In that case, it's really quite silly that `IHasXmlNode` isn't there, because the type returned (`DocumentXPathNavigator`) does have a `GetNode` method. Both the type and the method are `internal` and so not accessible through a neat interface. If you're not averse to some reflection, you could get at the method that way. If you're really up for it, you could even introduce a class `IHasXmlNode` with an explicit conversion operator for `XPathNavigator` so the client code can look the same.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `CreateNavigator` method returns `XPathNavigator` instead of `DocumentXPathNavigator`. With reflection i can't find `GetNode` method for `XPathNavigator`

Comment: Posted an answer that #worksforme in .NET Core 1.1. `CreateNavigator` returns an internal type that inherits from `XPathNavigator`.

Answer (score 2):

.NET Core 1.1 doesn't have `IHasXmlNode`, but it does have all the ingredients needed to implement a facsimile of it:

```
#if NETCOREAPP1_1
  class IHasXmlNode {
    readonly MethodInfo getNode;
    readonly XPathNavigator navigator;
    IHasXmlNode(XPathNavigator navigator) {
      this.navigator = navigator;
      this.getNode = navigator.GetType().GetTypeInfo().GetMethod("GetNode", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
      if (this.getNode == null) {
          throw new InvalidCastException($"{navigator.GetType()} cannot implement IHasXmlNode as it does not have a GetNode method.");
      };
    }

    public XmlNode GetNode() {
      return (XmlNode) getNode.Invoke(navigator, new object[] { });
    }

    public static implicit operator IHasXmlNode(XPathNavigator navigator) {
      return new IHasXmlNode(navigator);
    }
  }
#endif
```

This class is not a drop-in replacement for `IHasXmlNode` (as it is not a real interface, so operators like `is` and `as` will fail), but it will make code that simply converts work. The reflection could be optimized with `Linq.Expressions`, if necessary.